# ELemento estatico com vuerouter

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Tenho uma aplicação que usa vue-router, porem ela tambem tem a necessidade de realizar login, e com este login vem a mudança no cabeçalho, onde ficará login e registrar, ou painel, mas em casos especificos.

Estou usando vue router, há forma deste elemento estatico mudar apenas ao ser setada a variavel na session? ou há um elemento que possa ser usado como template dentro de uma aplicação vue para ser rederizada uma vez?

Não sei como resolver este problema, se puderem me ajudar, grato.

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes? Não está muito claro como sua aplicação está construída.

Comment: Eu estou usando SPA, e faço uma consulta, e quero que alguns links estejam disponivel caso logado, e outros para login e registrar caso não.

Tambem desejo que o layout, como template seja dinamico, usando Vue para rederizar, mas sem recarregar e evitar colocar um codigo em todas as paginas a ser rederizadas.

Answer (score 3):

voce pode pôr utilizar o `v-if="this.$route.name.match('route-name')"`, nesse caso, o bloco só aparecerá caso a rota tenha o mesmo nome da rota atual.